Laravel Blade error directive to PHP equivalent
I'm having trouble understanding the logic behind the Laravel @error blade directive. How does it work with $message enclosed within the @error directive? How does it know which $message to display? I would like to understand the PHP equivalent and how it operates behind the scenes.
@error('name')
   <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
     <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
   </span>
@enderror


See framework code.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/11.x/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/Concerns/CompilesErrors.php
The first commit is easier to understand.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/d5b80d727b6e426ce424be79b6016838c368504c
Similar code in older Laravel. @error just shortened this.
@if ($errors->has('name'))
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/Console/stubs/make/views/auth/register.stub#L20

Hey! I saw you are contributing nicely in other questions too, I never saw someone new already stating to check (and link) source code, so please continue to do so, that truly adds the value that most answers lack (on the Laravel tag)
